# How can I know the body content is outputted (then cannot use the header function)?

Tags: php

How can I know the body content is outputted (then cannot use the header function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the boolean-returning function `headers_sent` to determine if headers have been fully sent (implying that some content has also been sent too).

Answer (score 1):

By checking the return value of `headers_sent()`

```
if(!headers_sent())
```